# Access $display_submitted in page template

Tags: theming

Is there a way to access a node's $display_submitted Boolean value from within a page.tpl.php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While normally done in `node.tpl.php`, if the page is a node view page, the `$node` variable is also available in `page.tpl.php`

You can then use something like:

```
if (isset($node)) {
  // Check if display submitted variable is set for this node type
  if (variable_get('node_submitted_'. $node->type, 0)) {
    // Do stuff
  }
}
```

An alternative approach would be adding the required logic instead to an implementation of

[`hook_preprocess_page`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_page/7)

*Bonus update*: You can see the `$node` variable added to `page.tpl.php` in core [`template_preprocess_page`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_page/7)

```
if ($node = menu_get_object()) {
  $variables['node'] = $node;
}
```